# array.prototype..forEach function skipped with values in variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem, i have a Firebase Firestore Database connected to my React.JS Project, where users can enroll to courses. Now if i'm trying to load the users collection from the DB it returns 1 entry.

```
    const fetchAthletes = async () => {
        debugger
        try {
            const athletes: Array<any> = [];
            const athleteRef = collection(db, COLLECTION_NAME_ATHLETE);
            const getAthleteQuery = query(athleteRef, where('user', '==', userAuthToken.accessToken));
            const querySnapshot = await getDocs(getAthleteQuery)
            if (querySnapshot.docs) {
                //this for each gets skipped, even when querySnapshot.doc has values in it
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    athletes.push({
                        id: doc.id,
                        ...doc.data()
                    });
                    setAthletes(athletes as Array<Athlete>);
                })
            }
        } catch (error: unknown) {
            enqueueSnackbar((error as string), { variant: 'error', autoHideDuration: 3000 })
        }
    }
```

But when i want to loop over it via array.prototype.map it always skips it.

I debbuged through the funtion and found out that docs from Firestore is set with values tbat i wanna recieve.

[Data returned by Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUJ07.png)

I have no clue why it doesn't work. Any idea or help is appreciated

Comment: You should probably do `querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) ...`

Comment: You should edit the question to show the code that *doesn't* work, not the code that does work.

Comment: The code shown above doesn't work,it works fine till the comment iinside the function fetchAtheltes, then it skips the forEach function even if there are values inside the querySnapshot

Comment: You're also overwriting the `athletes` state at each iteration when you invoke `setAthletes`. You're better off mapping `querySnapshot.docs` into an array and then setting the new state _once_.

Comment: `querySnapshot.docs` is always an array, albeit sometimes empty. This means that `if (querySnapshot.docs)` will always be `true` and if `docs` is actually empty, the callback to `forEach` won't be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than attempt to individually set each doc into state, build up your array and set the entire thing into state

```ts
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(getAthleteQuery);
setAthletes(querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
  id: doc.id,
  ...doc.data(),
}));
```